# Finding the on-screen height of straight walls in raycasting rendering

Tags: raycasting

I have an issue to find the correct height of walls to make them straight in raycasting rendering.

This is how I calculate the height of the wall which is `h_seen`:

```
dist_w = sqrt(pow((w->cam->position.x - w->cam->rays[i].endPoint.x), 2) + pow((w->cam->position.y - w->cam->rays[i].endPoint.y), 2));
distortion = dist_w * tCos(w->cam->fov / 2 - (i * w->cam->fov / WIN_W));
if (distortion)
    h_seen = dist_c * wall_h / distortion;
//printf("h_seen = %f\n", h_seen);
y = cam_h - (h_seen / 2) - 1;
```

This is a screenshot of the problem [image] I have fisheye effect, if i use depth directly

```
    if (l == 0)
    {
        raytravel.y = w->cam->rays[i].endPoint.y - w->cam->position.y;
        raytravel.x = w->cam->rays[i].endPoint.x - w->cam->position.x;
        depth = raytravel.x * dir.x + raytravel.y * dir.y;
        h_seen = dist_c * wall_h / depth;
        y = cam_h - (h_seen / 2) - 1;
        if (hit == 1)
            while (++y < (cam_h + (h_seen / 2)))
                put_pixel_img(w, WIN_W - i + WIDTH_MM, y + 150, 0xff0000);
    }
```

[image]

// Direction of each ray inside the while loop

```
if ((hit = intersection(w, l, &dir)))
        w->cam->rays[i].endpoint = w->cam->intersection;
else
    {
        w->cam->rays[i].endpoint.x = w->cam->position.x + w->cam->raylength * tcos((w->cam->angle + w->cam->fov / 2) - (i * (w->cam->fov / limit)));
        w->cam->rays[i].endpoint.y = w->cam->position.y + w->cam->raylength * tsin((w->cam->angle + w->cam->fov / 2) - (i * (w->cam->fov / limit))); // limit is just the screen width
    }
```

Comment: What data types are each of these variables? Is there a chance you're getting any integer rounding earlier in the computation than you wanted it?

Comment: they are doubles and the only int that I use is the pixel to draw!

Comment: Can you show us how you're choosing the direction to shoot each ray?

Comment: Looks like you're still fanning out your rays by equal angular spacing. Remember I told you in the comments below that this choice is not correct for rendering on a flat screen. It also looks like you might be using the ray direction in your depth calculation, instead of the camera's forward vector (which should not vary from one ray to the next)

Comment: Yeah! It was my bad, now the fisheye effect is removed so thank you but the walls are not straight when i look along a wall, you gave me this link https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/156853/39518 but I don't understand your variables forwrd_x, forward_y, right_x and right_y and mostly the way you compute them.

Comment: That's sounding like a different question than the one asked above. Forward is a unit vector in the direction your camera is facing. Right is a vector perpendicular to that, running along the projection plane. So you can form each ray direction from a sum of forward plus some (positive or negative) amount of right. If you need more detail than that, you may want to ask a new question specific to that topic.

Comment: Am I supposed to open a new topic without closing this one?

Comment: The new images don't show the jagged irregular pattern you were originally dealing with, so I'd say that part of the problem is solved. In the process, it revealed a different problem. I think it's neatest to ask each question about one specific issue, but if you prefer you can edit this question to describe the problem more holistically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your calculation of "distortion," and get rid of some extra trigonometry & divisions, by recognizing that it's actually the depth of the hit point along your camera's forward direction. So, if you keep a unit vector in the direction the camera is facing...

```
// Vector from the camera to the ray hit using vector subtraction.
rayTravel = w->cam->rays[i].endPoint - w->cam->position;

// Dot product of ray onto camera's unit forward vector.
depth = rayTravel.x * w->cam->forward.x + rayTravel.y * w->cam->forward.y;

// Visible wall height is proportional to true height divided by depth.
h_seen = dist_c * wall_h / depth;
```

I don't have enough of your raycaster to verify whether this distortion calculation was the source of the problem, but this simplification should at least reduce the surface area for bugs and help narrow down the cause further. ;)

Comment: Can I send you my project in DM to verify this ? I have been looking all day to fix this.

Comment: No, but if you find you're not getting answers that adequately address your problem, you can update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - enough detail for users to be able to reproduce the same effect in their own projects.

Comment: @NumLock: From your edit, it looks like you've added the `depth` value to your `distortion` calculation. This is incorrect. `depth` is to be used *instead of* `distortion`, as shown in the answer. Note how `h_seen` is computed directly from `dist_c`, `wall_h`, and `depth`, with no `distortion` variable at all.

Comment: Well! It feels like my understanding of the projection is wrong then? The distortion that i used is to remove the fisheye effect, so that's wrong and how am i supposed to get out the fishbowl?

Comment: [See this earlier answer about this topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/156853/39518). The short answer is that thinking of your rays as being fired at equal angular increments is usually not what you want. If you're drawing on a flat screen, then the angle between pixels at the edges of the screen as seen from the viewer's eye is actually smaller than the angle between adjacent pixels near the middle of the screen.

Comment: Wow! Quite impressed, how the angles at the edges of the screen can be smaller, i was thinking that the angle is obtained between the perpendicular distance from the viewer to the projection plane and the subsequent ray, so it makes sense that it will bigger than the rays(angles) near the perp. ray